# Unidirectional vs Bidirectional One-To-Many cascade different

Tags: hibernate, session, grails, grails-orm

I have following test that passes if the Rental Unit to Review has One-To-Many bidirectional relationship, however. It fails if Rental Unit to Review has Unidirectional One-to-Many relationship. How come? And how to make it pass for unidirectional as well?

Test (spock):

```
def "one-to-many relationship between RentalUnit and Review"() {
        when:"adding shared review will result referenced by last rental unit"
        def review3 = Review.build().save(flush: true)
        def rentalUnit1 = RentalUnit.build().addToReviews(review3).save(flush: true)
        def rentalUnit2 = RentalUnit.build().addToReviews(review3).save(flush: true)
        rentalUnit1.refresh()

        then:
        !rentalUnit1.reviews.contains(review3)
    }
```

Code:
Rental Unit class is the same both - Unidirectional and Bidirectional

```
class RentalUnit {
 ...
    static hasMany = [reviews:Review]

    static mapping = {
        reviews cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    }
...
}
```

In Unidirectional case, the Review class doesn't contain anything related to Rental Unit. In Bidirectional case, the Review has extra line:

```
static belongsTo = [rentalUnit: RentalUnit]
```

(For complete code, in my [blog](http://margotskapacs.com/2012/11/domain-object-one-to-many-relationship-in-grails-gorm-and-sql-relational-db/) )

Comment: What error do you get when it "doesn't work"

Comment: Hi Gregg, no error...the assertion fails

Comment: Condition not satisfied:

!rentalUnit1.reviews.contains(review3)
||           |       |        |
||           |       true     com.minnehahalofts.app.Review : 7
||           [com.minnehahalofts.app.Review : 7]
|com.minnehahalofts.app.RentalUnit : 4
false